# Sacar datos del array a variables independientes. MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, array

Tengo una consulta `SQL` que trae los datos que yo quiero perfectamente. Al hacer un `print_r` me lo muestra así:

```
Array ( [0] => 6 [idFormacion] => 6 ) Array ( [0] => 9 [idFormacion] => 9 )
```

`Array ( [0] => 12 [idFormacion] => 12 ) Array ( [0] => 14 [idFormacion] => 14 )`

`Array ( [0] => 15 [idFormacion] => 15 ) Array ( [0] => 16 [idFormacion] => 16 )`

Lo que intento es guardar en variables independientes cada valor del array.

```
$valor1 = 6;
$valor2 = 9;
```

**EDIT**

Mi consulta `SQL`:

```
SELECT alumnos_formacion.idFormacion 
  FROM alumnos_formacion INNER JOIN formacion
     on alumnos_formacion.idFormacion = formacion.idFormacion
WHERE alumnos_formacion.NIA=12345
```

**EDIT 2**

Hasta ahora tengo echo esto:

```
while($fila2 = $objetoBBDD->devolverFilasAssoc())
{
    foreach ($fila2 as $indice => $array)
    {
        ${'valor: '.$indice} = $array;
        echo $array;
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Lo que me muestra son las filas con los datos que necesito:

`6`

`9`

`12`

`14`

`15`

`16`

Lo que no consigo es meter cada valor en variables independientes. Por ejemplo:

`$formacion1 = 6`

`$formacion2 = 9`

etc.

Comment: Me parece *raro*  ese array, leyendo que los datos vienen de MySQL. Me da la impresión de que tu código, a nivel de consulta, se podría optimizar y traer los datos más limpios, mejor ordenados y sin tener que repetir tanto `idFormacion`...

Answer (score 1):

Por el formato del array que muestras podrías recorrer cada posicion de tu arreglo con un foreach haciendo referencia a la llave [0] que es donde esta guardando el valor que pones en tu ejemplo,:

```
foreach($tuarreglo as $indice => $tuarray) {
     ${"valor" . $indice } = $tuarray[0];
}
```

Así al final tendrías una variable por cada iteración.
O mejor podrías crear un arreglo donde guardes tus valores que necesitas:

```
$resultados = [];//Arreglo donde guardas los valores que te interesan
//$tuarreglo es el arreglo que contiene tu consulta
foreach($tuarreglo as $indice => $tuarray) {
        $resultados[$indice] = $tuarray[0];
    }
```

Comment: He echo esto:  `print_r($resultados[$indice]);` y me muestra esto: 669911111111. Me repite todos los numeros y los numeros de dos cifras, solo me muestra el primero, osea del numero 12, me muestra solo el uno

Answer (score 0):

hola fijate que en el while proba con `mysql_fetch_all`, esto te va a traer todas las filas de ese array...